# Change options in GCC c++ make files

Tags: makefile

I am making some code that I want to run on Redhat and my Cyclone board in my make file I do this:

```
IDIR = ../inc
SRC = CInterface.cpp
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
OUT = libtest.a
INCLUDES = -I.
CCFLAGS = -g -O3
CPPFLAGS=-g -O3
LDFLAGS = -g


Cyclone:
CCC = /opt/altera-linux/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-                    
          4.7-2012.11-20121123_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

RedHat:
CCC = g++
```

Then I can do:

```
make Cyclone
```

or

```
make Redhat
```

Depending on the target. I keep getting the error

```
make: CCC: Command not found
```

If I put that CCC outside of the if statement then it works.  How to do this kind of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what "if statement" you're referring to in your question.  But, presumably you're trying to use [target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html).  If that's the case, then the variable assignment must come on the same line as the target, not on the next line:

```
Cyclone: CCC = /opt/altera-linux/linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2012.11-20121123_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

RedHat: CCC = g++
```

Comment: I tried that but no luck. What if I want to add other options to that target?  Also an echo would be good so I know what has been built.

make: *** No rule to make target `RedHat'.  Stop.

Comment: I answered what I could based on your question.  However, you give virtually no information.  The makefile bit you provide has no detail at all in it: there must be more to the makefile than what you've specified.  Make cannot guess what you mean when you say `make RedHat`: you have to modify your makefile to TELL it what you want to happen.  The error you're seeing _No rule to make target_ means you've asked for a target `RedHat` to be created but not given make any instructions on HOW it should be created.  At least you want to declare it `.PHONY`, but you'll need more besides.